# Organizing commands with HashMap (Bukkit)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a plugin that has lots of commands and I need to organize the commands so I put each command into different classes. I want to make only one CommandExecutor that puts the value and the class into a HashMap and then call that executor in my main class. Can somebody give an example for this?

I don't want to use the basic `getCommand("command").setExecutor(new Commands());` because it looks silly after 20 command. I am googling for this for 3 day now and I didn't find any useful example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do something like:

```
HashMap<String, CommandExecutor> commands = new HashMap<String, CommandExecutor>;

commands.put("firstcommand", new FirstCommand());
commands.put("secondcommand", new SecondCommand());

for (String name : commands.keySet()) {
    getCommand(name).setExecutor(commands.get(name));
}
```